# ¿ Como Asociar Extension de Archivo a Mi Aplicacion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Desarrollo una App que crea archivos con una extension .klm  lo que nesecito hacer es que al hacer Click en este tipo de archivos se abra mi aplicacion ...Como Puedo Hacerlo ???

Comment: [Como asociar una aplicacion a un tipo de archivo](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18539/windows-7-change-default-programs)

Comment: Si piensas distribuir tu aplicación con ClickOnce es muy sencillo. Si no tampoco es complicado, debes añadir una clave al registro en `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Classes`

Comment: ok reviso y comento ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucione ...Invokando el Metodo Asociar desde el evento Load de mi formulario

```
  public void Asociar()
        {
            if (GetProgIdFromExtension(".jll") == null && GetProgIdFromExtension(".jll") == "")
            {
                LinkExtension(".jll", "SudokuEdu", "SudokuEdu", "open", "SudokuEduDesc");
            }
        }
        public void LinkExtension(string extension, string executableFileName, string programId,string command, string description = "")
        {
            string linkedProgramID;
            RegistryKey registryKey = null;
            RegistryKey registryKeyShell = null;

            // El comando predeterminado es open
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(command))
                command = "open";
            // Obtiene la descripción
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
                description = $"{extension} Descripción de {programId}";
            // Normaliza la extensión
            if (!extension.StartsWith("."))
                extension = "." + extension;
            // Obtiene el ID del programa a partir de la extensión
            linkedProgramID = GetProgIdFromExtension(extension);
            // Si no hay nada asociado, se crean las claves, si hay algo asociado se modifican
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkedProgramID) || linkedProgramID.Length == 0)
            {
                // Crear la clave con la extensión
                registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(extension);
                registryKey?.SetValue("", programId);
                // Crea la clave con el programa
                registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(programId);
                registryKey?.SetValue("", description);
                // Crea la clave con el comando
                registryKeyShell = registryKey?.CreateSubKey($"shell\\{command}\\command");
            }
            else
            {
                // Abrimos la clave indicando que vamos a escribir para que nos permita crear nuevas subclaves.
                registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(linkedProgramID, true);
                registryKeyShell = registryKey?.OpenSubKey($"shell\\{command}\\command", true);
                // Si es un comando que se añade, no existirá
                if (registryKeyShell == null)
                    registryKeyShell = registryKey?.CreateSubKey(programId);

            }
            // Si tenemos la clave de registro del Shell
            if (registryKeyShell != null)
            {
                registryKeyShell.SetValue("", $"\"{executableFileName}\" \"%1\"");
                registryKeyShell.Close();
            }
        }
        ///  Método para obtener el ID de programa de una extensión
        private string GetProgIdFromExtension(string extension)
        {
            string strProgramID = "";

            // Obtiene el ID del programa
            using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension))
            {
                if (registryKey?.GetValue("") != null)
                {
                    // Obtiene el ID
                    strProgramID = registryKey.GetValue("").ToString();
                    // Cierra la clave
                    registryKey.Close();
                }
            }
            // Devuelve el ID del programa
            return strProgramID;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para asociar una aplicación a una extensión de un archivo tendrás que utilizar el registro de Widnows, concretamente la rama `shell`.

Puedes utilizar este código:

```
    using Microsoft.Win32;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Asocia una extensión con un ejecutable y una acción
    /// </summary>
    public void LinkExtension(string extension, string executableFileName, string programId,
                              string command = "open", string description = "")
    { 
        string linkedProgramID;
        RegistryKey registryKey = null;
        RegistryKey registryKeyShell = null;

        // El comando predeterminado es open
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(command))
            command = "open";
        // Obtiene la descripción
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
            description = $"{extension} Descripción de {programId}";
        // Normaliza la extensión
        if (!extension.StartsWith("."))
            extension = "." + extension;
        // Obtiene el ID del programa a partir de la extensión
        linkedProgramID = GetProgIdFromExtension(extension);
        // Si no hay nada asociado, se crean las claves, si hay algo asociado se modifican
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkedProgramID) || linkedProgramID.Length == 0)
        {   
            // Crear la clave con la extensión
            registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(extension);
            registryKey?.SetValue("", programId);
            // Crea la clave con el programa
            registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(programId);
            registryKey?.SetValue("", description);
            // Crea la clave con el comando
            registryKeyShell = registryKey?.CreateSubKey($"shell\\{command}\\command");
        }
        else
        {   
            // Abrimos la clave indicando que vamos a escribir para que nos permita crear nuevas subclaves.
            registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(linkedProgramID, true);
            registryKeyShell = registryKey?.OpenSubKey($"shell\\{command}\\command", true);
            // Si es un comando que se añade, no existirá
            if (registryKeyShell == null)
                registryKeyShell = registryKey?.CreateSubKey(programId);

        }
        // Si tenemos la clave de registro del Shell
        if (registryKeyShell != null)
        {   
            registryKeyShell.SetValue("", $"\"{executableFileName}\" \"%1\"");
            registryKeyShell.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Método para obtener el ID de programa de una extensión
    /// </summary>
    private string GetProgIdFromExtension(string extension)
    { 
        string strProgramID = "";

        // Obtiene el ID del programa
        using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension))
        {   
            if (registryKey?.GetValue("") != null)
            {   
                // Obtiene el ID
                strProgramID = registryKey.GetValue("").ToString();
                // Cierra la clave
                registryKey.Close();
            }
        }
        // Devuelve el ID del programa
        return strProgramID;
    }
```

Comment: Me devuelve este ERROR : Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Security.SecurityException' en mscorlib.dll

Información adicional: Acceso denegado al Registro solicitado.

Comment: Es posible que `Registry.ClassesRoot` solicite permiso de administración, prueba con otra clave como `Registry.LocalMachine`o `Registry.CurrentUser` aunque no sé si éstas accederán a la función que estás buscando.

Comment: Probe con Registry.LocalMachineo y Registry.CurrentUser no devuelve ERROR ...luego voy al archivo .jll hago Clikc pero no hace nada

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando Windows 10? Puede que el modo de asociar las extensiones haya cambiado. ¿Podrías probar con la respuesta a esta pregunta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application? Si funciona, habría que editar la respuesta con el nuevo código

Comment: ok...pruebo y te comento....

Comment: Hola : Jose Antonio Bautista ... Pude Asociar extension e icono. Asi Menu Proyecto -- Propiedades -- Publicar --Opciones ....Pero desde el codigo de la Aplicacion no pude